# Importing checked out files on TFS from one machine to another

Tags: visual-studio-2010, version-control, workspace

I have new files added on TFS and some other checked out but on my older workspace. Now my machine is changed and I want to have those files on my new workspace.
Is there any way to have these changes replicated/imported to my new workspace?

Comment: Do you still have access to your old machine and workspace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you still have access to your old machine, you can either check in the changes or put them on a [Shelveset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181404%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) (if you don't want to check them in for everyone to see). Then on your new machine either do a Get Latest Version (when you had checked the code in) or Unshelve the changes to your new machine.

If you don't have access to your old machine, then these changes are not available. TFS doesn't get the changes version of your files until you either check in or shelve. You'll have to consider them lost and unrecoverable.

If you have access to the old machine, but the old machine can no longer access TFS, copy the old workspace to the new machine and then use the [Compare folder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385986%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) option to merge your changes into your new workspace.

To prevent accidentally losing your changes you can install an extension which [automatically shelves your changes](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/080540cb-e35f-4651-b71c-86c73e4a633d).

Comment: I do not have access to either my old machine or workspace and I could see that I've lost my changes. Nevertheless, thank you for TFS auto shelve, which will make my life better in future.

Answer (score 2):

You have to check in the changes or create a shelveset on your old workstation and take a get latest on your new computer.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181403(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: unfortunately this is true. Or you could check out the files on your new workstation, and manually copy them from you old workstation and replace the files on you new workstation.

Comment: If your changes are unfinished a shelveset is recommended so you don't interrupt other coders who works in the same branch.